# how to set value in text field in angularjs on row click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to set value on text field when row is click but I got the value of row text but I am not able to set value on text field .

here is concept

```
<li ng-click="rowclick(station)" class="item" ng-repeat="station in data.data | filter:stationCode :startsWith">{{station.stationName+"-("+station.stationCode+")"}}</li>
```

I right **ng-click="rowclick(station)"** event when any row is click .But I need to set value whatever is selected ..so first type **"b"** character in text field 
here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKyZW

```
 $scope.rowclick=function(station){
     $scope.stationCode=station.stationCode;
          //  $scope.$apply();
   }
```

Thannks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving stationCode, give SEARCH.stationCode for the model. The problem is with the scoping. The stationCode that you are setting in rowclick function is not in the same scope as the one that you are expecting

See this modified code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGYPWj

`$scope.SEARCH.stationCode` is the change that I made. I also initialised `$scope.SEARCH = {};`

Comment: Thanks great solution..can we hide list after selecting one item

Comment: Sure. You can use a flag that holds true when you select (click on) a value and becomes false when the textbox changes - and use that to show/hide the list.